# Efficiently counting rows by date, adjusted for timezone

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-performance

I have a table with a schema that looks like this:

- id (uuid; pk)
- timestamp (timestamp)
- category (bpchar)
- flaged_as_spam (bool)
- flagged_as_bot (bool)
- ... (other metadata)

I have an index on this table that looks like this:

```
CREATE INDEX time_index ON events_table USING btree (flagged_as_bot, flagged_as_spam, category, "timestamp") WHERE ((flagged_as_bot = false) AND (flagged_as_spam = false))
```

I run queries against this table to generate line charts representing the number of events that occurred each day. However, I want the line chart to be adjusted for the user's timezone. Currently, I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT
    date_trunc('day', timestamp + INTERVAL '-5 hour') AS ts,
    category,
    COUNT(*) AS count
FROM
    events_table
WHERE
    category = 'the category'
    AND flagged_as_bot = FALSE
    AND flagged_as_spam = FALSE
    AND timestamp >= '2018-05-04T00:00:00'::timestamp
    AND timestamp < '2018-10-31T17:57:59.661664'::timestamp
GROUP BY
    ts,
    category
ORDER BY
    1 ASC
```

In most cases, for categories with under 100,000 records, this is quite fast:

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=8908.56..8958.18 rows=1985 width=70) (actual time=752.886..753.301 rows=124 loops=1)
  Group Key: (date_trunc('day'::text, ("timestamp" + '-05:00:00'::interval))), category
  ->  Sort  (cost=8908.56..8913.52 rows=1985 width=62) (actual time=752.878..752.983 rows=797 loops=1)
        Sort Key: (date_trunc('day'::text, ("timestamp" + '-05:00:00'::interval)))
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 137kB
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on listens  (cost=552.79..8799.83 rows=1985 width=62) (actual time=748.683..752.568 rows=797 loops=1)
              Recheck Cond: ((category = '7248c3b8-727e-4357-a267-e9b0e3e36d4b'::bpchar) AND ("timestamp" >= '2018-05-04 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND ("timestamp" < '2018-10-31 17:57:59.661664'::timestamp without time zone))
              Filter: ((NOT flagged_as_bot) AND (NOT flagged_as_spam))
              Rows Removed by Filter: 1576
              Heap Blocks: exact=1906
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on time_index  (cost=0.00..552.30 rows=2150 width=0) (actual time=748.324..748.324 rows=2373 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: ((category = '7248c3b8-727e-4357-a267-e9b0e3e36d4b'::bpchar) AND ("timestamp" >= '2018-05-04 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND ("timestamp" < '2018-10-31 17:57:59.661664'::timestamp without time zone))
                    Planning time: 0.628 ms
Execution time: 753.362 ms"
```

For categories with a very large number of records (>100,000), the index is not used and the query is very slow:

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=1232229.95..1287491.60 rows=2126204 width=70) (actual time=14649.671..17178.955 rows=181 loops=1)
  Group Key: (date_trunc('day'::text, ("timestamp" + '-05:00:00'::interval))), category
  ->  Sort  (cost=1232229.95..1238072.10 rows=2336859 width=62) (actual time=14643.887..16031.031 rows=3070695 loops=1)
        Sort Key: (date_trunc('day'::text, ("timestamp" + '-05:00:00'::interval)))
        Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 216200kB
        ->  Seq Scan on listens  (cost=0.00..809314.38 rows=2336859 width=62) (actual time=0.015..9572.722 rows=3070695 loops=1)
              Filter: ((NOT flagged_as_bot) AND (NOT flagged_as_spam) AND ("timestamp" >= '2018-05-04 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND ("timestamp" < '2018-10-31 17:57:59.661664'::timestamp without time zone) AND (category = '3b634b32-bb82-4f56-ada4-f4b7bc4288a5'::bpchar))
              Rows Removed by Filter: 8788028
              Planning time: 0.239 ms
              Execution time: 17228.314 ms
```

My assumption is that this the index is not used because the overhead of using the index is far higher than simply performing a table scan. And of course, I imagine this to be because of the use of `date_trunc` to calculate the date to group by.

I've considered what could be done here. Here are some of my thoughts:

- Most simply, I could create an expression index for each timezone offset that I care about (generally GMT/EST/CST/MST/PST). This would take up a good deal of space and each index would be infrequently used, but it would theoretically allow for index-only scans.
- I could create an expression index truncated by hour. I don't know if this would help Postgres to optimize the query, though.
- I could calculate each of the date ranges in advance and using some subquery magic, query the event count per range. I also don't know if this will yield any improvement.

Before I go down a rabbit hole, I figured I'd reach out to see if anyone has any thoughts.

Comment: Could you post results of A) EXPLAIN SELECT ….  and  B) SHOW INDEX FROM events_table;  and  C) SHOW CREATE TABLE events_table?

Comment: @WilsonHauck Perhaps I wasn't explicit in my question, but this is for Postgres, not MySQL.

Comment: Does Postgres have tools (by another name) to provide this type of information?

Comment: @WilsonHauck You can see the CREATE INDEX command for the index I created in the question (from `select * from pg_indexes`). The outputs of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` are shown. I don't have the full schema handy, but the query shown is essentially the only one that matters in this case.

Comment: consider making the timestamp selections FIRST in the WHERE and then ORDER the index elements in the same order as listed in the updated WHERE list.  This should reduce the # rows retrieved to achieve your results.  I like your method of reducing the INDEX volume of data, saves space in this SPECIAL PURPOSE index.  However, it's presence could cause other queries to miss some rows when timestamp is chosen by the optimizer for solving any query using this table.  You might want to remove the WHERE in the index creation to follow a typical use of indexes.

Comment: @WilsonHauck 100% of production queries against this table specify the `flagged_as_spam = false` and `flagged_as_bot = false` conditions; so far I've found no reason to believe that the Postgres query planner has any issue choosing an index when the query is constructed correctly with those conditions.

I tried moving the `timestamp` to be first the `WHERE` clause, but it did not have a meaningful impact on execution time and did not change the output of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.

As I mentioned, and as you can see, the issue is that the index _isn't being used_, not that it's being used poorly.

Comment: Are the index sequence of elements in the same order as elements listed in the WHERE clause?   You may find that the order MUST be the same to be used.  It is possible you also must use FORCE index use.

Comment: @WilsonHauck In my question, you'll see that I note that the index _is_ used for queries where the number of aggregated rows is relatively small. For an identical query with a different value for `category` (where the number of aggregated rows is very large), the index is not used. I show this in the question.

Comment: This may be important to the optimizer. Are the index sequence of elements in the same order as elements listed in the WHERE clause? You may find that the order MUST be the same to be used. It is possible you also must use FORCE index use.

Comment: @WilsonHauck The ordering is identical. Forcing the index use (using Postgres flags) results in roughly equivalent execution times or slightly worse due to the additional layer of indirection for a very large number of rows.

I'm not looking for a solution that forces the use of the index, I'm looking for an efficient way to count these rows that doesn't involve creating one index per timezone.

Comment: Do the SEARCH data types exactly match data type of SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name?  That is likely a detail requirement for the optimizer matching process.  If you could post your current query and SHOW CREATE TABLE, I will look at it again.